# Which approach is better for multi-language DB if there are only two languages to support

Tags: mysql, laravel, multilingual

I am creating a DB for project with only two languages to support. Is it good idea to take two columns in same table or create another table for saving the translations.

**Approach 1 :**
Table_name : id,col1_en,col1_ar

**Approch 2 :**

Table_languages: id,lang

Table_name: id

Table_name_translations: id,language_id,table_name_id,col

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that you will never ever add another language to the site, working with two columns will query easier.

However if there is even the slightest doubt more languages will be added in the future, you should go with approach 2. It will prevent many headaches in the future.